# What version of Android does ARC currently emulate?

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I'm just trying to figure out what the most compatible version of a particular .apk is most likely to work with ARC running in Chrome Browser on Windows 10

I've only tried downloading the latest version .apk of Samsung Smart Things and that fails.

NA

I expect that I need to run the latest version of .apk that is compatible with the emulated/virtualized android kernal in ARC for it to work.

Comment: I don''t think ARC has been maintained in years.

Comment: @CommonsWare You would think so but the chrome app got updated on June 18, 2018. I would assume it wont be updated again though.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I can install the ARC Welder extension for Google Chrome, locate my .apk, but the loading dialog just keeps sitting there forever and I never get to the next step.